# Can this problem be solved by dynamic programming?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given *n, m, d*. The answer is stored in *sum* variable in the below code:

```
int x = m / d;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    sum += mobius(i) * ((x / i) ^ n);
}
```

Now the problem is to find the total *sum % (10^9 + 7)* when *d* varies from *[l, r]* with *n, m* as mentioned above. I have only been able to do it by brute-force, but the constraints are *1 <= n, m, l, r <= 10^7*. So the brute-force solution cannot pass the time limit.
Is there some underlying overlapping subproblem and optimal substructure property to this problem which can be used to solve the problem by dynamic programming?

Link: [Mobius Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), I have pre-calculated the mobius function in *O(nlogn)*.
**Edit:** Given *t, n, m*. Where *t* is the number of test cases,
*l, r* is given *t* times. We have to output the total sum as mentioned above.

Sample Input:
T : 2
N : 3, M : 10
Values of *l* and *r*
9 9
10 10

Sample Output:
1
1

Comment: Could you link us to the problem, so that we know it's not for a currently active programming contest?  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you need a polynom computation algorithm : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method ... For the problem itself (computing each sum while m and d change), I am not sure I understand correctly. As @j_random_hacker stated, a link to the problem would be good

Comment: The problem is from our university past internal programming contest. So i am sorry but the link is not available anymore. I can provide the problem statement if that would suffice.

Comment: OK.  DP might be involved, but I suspect the key will be somehow exploiting the Möbius inversion property to make a large number of terms cancel out.  Wish I could give you a better suggestion!

Comment: Yes i thought about it. All the values with mobius(i) = -1 can be used to somehow merge the problem into smaller subproblems. But not able to reach to the final solution.

Comment: Is the `^` in your code snippet a XOR or an exponential?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat : exponential.

Comment: When l = 1 and r = 10 the desired problem output is 1 integer or 10 integers? An example of input and desired output will be very useful in your question.

Comment: @AdamStelmasnzczyk : In this case the output will have only 1 integer as only 1 value of [l, r] pair is given. Output will contain t values, t is the number of test cases as mentioned in the Edited part. I am adding a sample output also now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when you divide m by d to compute x, there will only be about `2*sqrt(m)` unique values for x.

This means you only need to trigger the second loop for each unique value of x.

Similarly, in the computation of `x/i`, there will only be about `2*sqrt(x)` unique values for `(x/i)`.  This means you only need to compute `(x/i)^n` for each unique value.

For each unique value of `x/i` there will be a range of i values that produce this value.

You will then need to add up `mobius[i]` for all the values of i that produce the same output.  This can be done by preparing an array with the cumulative sum of the Mobius function (this cumulative sum is called the [Mertens function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function)).

For example, if

```
M[k] = sum[ Mobius(i) for i = 1..k ]
```

then

```
sum[ Mobius(i) for i = low..high ] = M[high] - M[low-1]
```

Overall the complexity is `O( sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) ) = O(n)` (in addition to the time spent computing the Mobius function).

Comment: That really reduces the time complexity!
But won't there be additional time required for finding the range of i values that produces those x/i values ?

Comment: I just figured that out.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I think it's possible to get a sub-linear algorithm (O(n^2/3)). This problems looks like can be solved using the dirichlet hyperbola method.